# (How) can a VS Code extension access [language]-specific `settings.json` sub-section values?

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

Example: extension code can very trivially determine the value of `editor.formatOnSave`. But from what I can tell and have tried, it seems nigh impossible to query the current document/editor whether that setting is effective *right there, right now*. With `[language]`-specific sub-sections it may be enabled for Go but disabled for others for example --- or vice versa. And "some" (ie. mine) extension might "need" (ie. want) to know about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to use the documented `getConfiguration("language").get("setting")` it won't work. But there is a *workaround* to access what you want.

Let's suppose you want to load `editor.formatOnSave` for `markdown` files. If you look at `User Settings`, you will see it stored like this:

```
["markdown"]: {
    "editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

You just have to load the configuration object and access the desired properties, like this:

```
let markdownObject = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration("[markdown]");
if (markdownObject["editor.formatOnSave"]) {
    console.log("[markdown].editor.formatOnSave is TRUE");
}
```

It's important to note that you must use `[markdown]` (between brackets) because that is how it is represented on the `JSON` file.

Also note that this *workaround* will not give you access to settings that *are not overridden* for languages. In that case, you must use/combine the documented API.